# javascript anonymous function : how is this variable exposed in global namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand how this library can make NS var accessible in global namespace since it's declared with var, can you explain.

Update: if Ns is not global then what's the purpose of doing var NS = namespace = {}; ?

http://blog.stephenrushing.com/index.php/javascript/custom-events-in-javascript/

```
(function () {
    var NS = namespace = {};
    var EVENTS = NS.events = {};
    var eventify = EVENTS.eventify = function (target1, targetN) {
            for (var t = 0; t < arguments.length; t++) {
                var target = arguments[t];
                if (!target.__listeners) {
                    if (!target.events) target.events = {};
                    target.__listeners = {};
                    target.dispatchEvent = function (eventType, eventData) {
                        if (this.events[eventType]) this.events[eventType].dispatch(this, eventData);
                    };
                    target.addEventListener = function (eventType, callback, bubbles) {
                        return new EVENTS.Listener(this, eventType, callback, bubbles);
                    };
                    target.removeEventListener = function (eventType, callback) {
                        var listeners = this.__listeners[eventType];
                        for (var l = 0; listeners && l < listeners.length; l++)
                        if (listeners[l] === callback || listeners[l].callback === callback) listeners.splice(l, 1);
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    var Event = EVENTS.Event = function (type) {
            this.type = type;
            this.history = [];
        }
    Event.prototype = {
        bubbleTo: null,
        currentTarget: null,
        dispatch: function (target, eventData, currentTarget) {
            this.target = target;
            this.currentTarget = currentTarget || target;
            var timeStamp = new Date();
            this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
            this._stopProp = false;
            if (!currentTarget) {
                var histObj = {
                    eventData: eventData,
                    timeStamp: timeStamp
                };
            } else {
                var histObj = currentTarget.events[this.type].history[currentTarget.events[this.type].history.length - 1];
            }
            histObj.target = target;
            histObj.currentTarget = currentTarget || target;
            this.history.push(histObj);
            var listeners = target.__listeners[this.type],
                result;
            for (var l = 0; listeners && l < listeners.length; l++) {
                var listener = listeners[l];
                if (eventData) result = listener.callback.call(target, this, eventData);
                else result = listener.callback.call(target, this);
                if (typeof (result) !== "undefined" && result !== null) this.result = result;
                if (this._stopImmProp) break;
            }
            if (this.bubbleTo !== null && !this._stopProp) this.bubbleTo.events[this.type].dispatch(this.bubbleTo, eventData, this.currentTarget);
        },
        result: true,
        _stopImmProp: false,
        stopImmediatePropagation: function () {
            this._stopImmProp = true
        },
        _stopProp: false,
        stopPropagation: function () {
            this._stopProp = true
        },
        target: null,
        type: null,
        history: null
    }
    var Listener = EVENTS.Listener = function (target, eventType, callback, bubbles) {
            this.target = target;
            this.callback = callback;
            this.bubbles = (bubbles !== null) ? bubbles : true;
            if (!target.events[eventType]) target.events[eventType] = this.event = new EVENTS.Event(eventType);
            this.event = target.events[eventType];
            if (!target.__listeners[eventType]) target.__listeners[eventType] = [];
            target.__listeners[eventType].push(this);
        }
    Listener.prototype = {
        bubbles: true,
        callback: function (evt, data) {},
        remove: function () {
            var idx = Array.indexOf(this.target.__listeners[this.event.type], this);
            this.target.__listeners[this.event.type].splice(idx, 1);
            delete this;
        },
        event: null,
        target: null
    }
})();
```

Comment: What makes you think that NS is global?

Comment: Actually I think that code has a bug, and it would throw an error in strict mode.  The problem is that it assigns the symbol "namespace" (not NS, which is as you say a local variable) without declaring it. Therefore, the global variable here is "namespace", but such implicit globals are a no-no.

Comment: In general, you can make something global in JS at least in two ways, one of them is setting property on global window object. I don't see however how NS would be global here.

Answer (score 3):

No reason why `NS` would be global (and it isn't, testing in Chrome). `namespace`, however, will be, because chained assignments will always do that (and hence should be avoided in JS, unless assigning to variables previously declared).

```
var NS = namespace = {};
```

is executed as:

```
namespace = {};
var NS = namespace;
```

**Update**

Judging from the blog post, the declaration of "namespace" as global is intentional.

So, the "usefulness" of the line is mostly to declare a global namespace object (`namespace` - in my opinion, that should have been done explicitly in order to show that the intent really is to make it global).

... and "at the same time", create a local, short, reference to it (`NS`). Other than it being short, it's also theoretically a tiny bit faster performance-wise to reference this local variable in the rest of his library code, rather than a "global" property of window (`namespace` is really `window.namespace`).

The bit that seems to confuse in this case is that in his blog, he refers to the global `namespace` object as `ns` (see the line "For this sample, ..."). In other words, for the purposes of the blog post, the line is really:

```
var NS = ns = {}; // which wouldn't exactly make its intent more clear.
```

Comment: Good catch about chained assignments. It's worth mentioning, that back in a day, declaring variable without explicit `var` keyword was breaking Internet Explorer.

Comment: @WTK: Never heard or encountered that one. :-) Although I do remember troubleshooting scripts in IE for people who had a variable named (for example) `menu` without "var" *and* an HTML element with `id="menu"`.

Comment: namespace is global but why would NS also global just because it refers to namespace ?

Comment: It wouldn't be, unless the browser has a bug, or there's more to the script that you haven't posted. Tested in Firefox 9.0.1, Chrome 16.0, IE 8. If you're referring to the blog post using "ns" globally, it appears that "namespace" being global is intentional, and the author mentions in the beginning of his post that "namespace" has been renamed to "ns".

Comment: The source code is from his site http://blog.stephenrushing.com/wp-content/uploads/javascript/customEvents/events.js . I don't understand the usefullness of the instruction var NS = namespace = {}; there must be a reason no ?

Comment: Updated the answer to explain.